# Inconsistent rails gem errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

Every other time I run a rake command, or start the server (script/server) I get gem install errors;

```
Missing these required gems:
  image_science  >= 0
  youtube_it  >= 0
```

But, if I ignore that (the gems are installed) and try again, then on the 2nd or 3rd attempt, it will work fine, no errors.

It seems like maybe there are multiple rails or rake installs, but `which rails` shows only '/usr/bin/rails' as does `which rake`

I'm wondering if maybe my app could have different requirements in different places? Is that possible?

Rails version is 2.3.15

**EDIT**
More output

```
You're running:
  ruby 1.8.7.358 at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
  rubygems 1.8.24 at /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8, /Users/<snip>/.gem/ruby/1.8,     /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide more information, like what version of Rails this app should be using.

Comment: Hi Ryan, I have added the rails version. I stupidly assumed that the tag would suggest rails 2 (as the other rails tags are version specific.) Thanks.